# WebView not opening this kind of url: https://www.ubt.esse3.u-gov.rash.al/auth/Login.do

Tags: javascript, java, android, url, webview

I am trying to make a webview for the webpage shown below, but it does not open. It opens other urls such as ww.google.com or others. But, this url which have a **.do** extension at the end, wont open.

Anyone knows how to help me ?

Thank you !

https://www.ubt.esse3.u-gov.rash.al/auth/Login.do

Comment: because It has to be fill the id and password before open website. For this solution check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43645391/webview-not-loading-page-after-form-submit/43648444#43648444)

Comment: @TranHieu  I will tryband let you know if it worked . Thanks in advance.

Comment: @TranHieu  With a little bit of changes it worked . Thank you for your help :)